# App crashes when network changes

Tags: iphone, ios

I have to fix some bugs in an app somebody else developed. I have not worked on iOS before.

The iOS app sends some data out every 15 seconds, this works fine. I can click the home button and go back into the app, works fine too.

Now the problem only comes when there is a change in the network, lets say I activate Flightmode.

When I go back into the app it crashes because of a `NSRangeException`. The problem is I can not get any Debug output out or anything, even if I put debug statements around all the places where this Exception can happen.

Could somebody give me a tip? How can a change in network have such a effect?

Comment: You may need a stack from the crash logs and some code around that stack for others to pinpoint.

Comment: Based on the NSRangeException error it sounds like you're trying to access an NSArray, substring of an NSString, or some other index-oriented object that is tanking. What happens if you toggle your development box's wifi on/off while you're running simulator with the app up and running?